# Is it possible to use an iPhone 5 with tracfone service byop?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to use an iPhone 5 with Tracfone's byop. However I can't seem to find the right sim card. At first Tracfone said that I needed an at&t SIM card but it doesn't work with iPhone 5 for it is much to big.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I recently purchased [this kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014X62KUE) I learned about on a deals forum.

It comes with SIM cards in standard, micro and nano sizes. I have not activated it yet but you can buy different levels of time to add. I have installed the card in my 4S but I still have time left on my non-smartphone tracfone.